# Modify mode's font-locking without changing source code

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting

Suppose I want to make additions to a major mode's syntax highlighting, how would I do this without modifying the major mode's source code?

Some ideas:

- Redefine variable in .emacs
- Define a minor mode with the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `font-lock-add-keywords`. See the Elisp manual, node [Customizing Keywords](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html).

The Elisp manual is your friend: `C-h i`, then choose it. In the manual, `i` is your friend. E.g., `i font-lock TAB`.